# is there a syntactic shortcut similar to coalesce for union?

Tags: sql

What I'm trying to do is:

```
select 
A.Fuzz
,A.Fizz
,B.Whiz
 from A
left outer join B
on A.Fuzzy B=Wuzzy
```

To replace:

```
select 
A.Fuzz
,A.Fizz
,B.Whiz
 from A
left outer join B
on A.Fuzzy B=Wuzzy
UNION ALL
select 
B.wuzz
,A.Fizz
,B.Whiz
 from A
left outer join B
on A.Fuzzy B=Wuzzy
```

Comment: Probably `CASE`, but it's hard to tell from what you have posted. What RDBMS? Some sample data would help too.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result please

Comment: If your RDBMS supports it, you could use a `full join`.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is something "near" what you think (done on MSSQL)?.  Pls in every question post sample data, expected result, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE A (ID INT, DESC_A VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,'A');
INSERT INTO A VALUES (2,'B');

CREATE TABLE B (ID INT, DESC_B VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO B VALUES (2,'Z');
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3,'Y');

SELECT COALESCE(A.ID, B.ID) AS ID
, A.DESC_A
, B.DESC_B
FROM A
FULL JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Output:

```
ID  DESC_A  DESC_B
1   A   NULL
2   B   Z
3   NULL    Y
```